# why query is showing 'invalid relational operator'

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, max, greatest-n-per-group

```
select * 
from employees
 where department_id,salary in (
    select department_id,max(salary) 
    from employees group by department_id
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You want tuple comparison - you need to surround the tuple of columns on the left side of `in` with parentheses:

```
select * 
from employees 
where (department_id,salary) in (
    select department_id, max(salary) from employees group by department_id
)
```

Note that this top-1-per-group query can be more efficiently phrased with window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select e.*, rank() over(partition by department_id order by salary desc nulls last) rn
    from employees e
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: We should hope the `SALARY` is never `null` - if it can be, the `null` rows will be ranked first when ordering `desc`. That is the default when using descending ordering. To be safe, we should add the `nulls last` option after `order by salary desc`.